# Does MKMapView support the "little man" street view?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

There is no little man icon to drag onto a street in a map.
Is there a way to enable him programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The MKMapView does not have support for the "little man" (Pegman) or Street View.

One alternative is to use the Google Maps Javascript API V3 directly.  In a UIWebView, load an html file (added as a resource in your app) containing a Google map.  For sample html files containing Street View, look for the streetview-*.html files on the [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html) page.

Another alternative is to call the Maps app from yours using `openURL:` and pass it a [Map Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1).  This will only work on the device (the simulator doesn't have the Maps app and will open the browser instead).